# Searching Youtube videos using Youtube Api V3

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

**PROBLEM:**
I am trying to do some testing of the Youtube Api V3 in Android Studio, and these test are mainly tasks like searching for videos, then playing a video you choose. However, after looking through this link [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword) I discovered that the com.google.api.services import didn't exist. The [jar](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) that I downloaded only came with imports such as com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer. Now according to that page I linked, it is supposedly possible to do what I want with the API, but I cannot figure it out.

**QUESTION:**
How am I supposed to use the sample from the link if the API doesn't even have the imports? Am I missing something that I didn't download? Let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it!

Comment: Google Play Services. Yes, you are missing it. Why are you using Jar files and not Gradle dependencies?

Comment: When I tried using the Gradle dependency from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) it actually didn't build correctly. Even then I am not sure if the correct imports will be there.